# $\overline{Y}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want to show:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $Y\subseteq X$. Then is $\overline{Y}$ closed.

For my proof I want to write $X\setminus\overline{Y}$ as union of open sets.

Proof:

It is $\overline{Y}=Y\cup\partial Y$.
Consider $X\setminus(Y\cup\partial Y)=\overline{Y}^c$.

Let $x\in X\setminus(Y\cup\partial Y)$. Hence $x\notin Y$ and $x\notin\partial Y$. 
Therefor for every neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ it is $U_x\cap Y=\emptyset$.

Hence $U_x\subseteq X\setminus Y$ and $\overline{Y}^c\subseteq\underbrace{\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x}_{\text{open}}\subseteq X\setminus Y$.

Now I want to show, that $\overline{Y}^c\supseteq\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x$.
Let $x'\in\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x$.

I have to show, that $x'\notin Y$ and $x'\notin\partial Y$.

Since $x'\notin\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x\subseteq X\setminus Y$ is $x\notin Y$.

Suppose $x'\in\partial Y$. Then holds for every neighborhood $U_{x'}$ of $x'$, that $Y\cap U_{x'}\neq\emptyset$ and $U_{x'}\cap (X\setminus Y)\neq\emptyset$.
Which contradicts, that $U_{x'}\subseteq X\setminus Y$.

We condlude, that $\overline{Y}^c=\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x$ open.
Hence $\overline{Y}$ is closed.

Can you verify my proof?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading through this, but the first thing that seems off to me is "Therefor for every neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ it is $U_x\cap Y=\emptyset$. " - This is not true if we, say, take the neighborhood $U_x = X$

Comment: Has the neigborhood not to be a subset of $X\setminus Y$?

Comment: I suppose you could be working off a different definition, but a neighborhood of a point $x$ is usually defined to be any open set containing $x$. Another (slightly less common) definition is that a neighborhood is any set containing an open set containing $x$. In either case, the set $X$ is a neighborhood of each of its points

Comment: My definition is, that $U\subseteq X$ is a neighborhood of $x$, if there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. But you are right. Do you see a way to fix my proof, or does it go down the dumpster?

Comment: That definition works only in a metric space, while not all topological spaces admit a metric. As for patching up your proof, I will have to continue reading, but it might very well be salvageable. It is true that $x$ is an interior point of the set $\bar{Y}^c$, so if we cheat and note this is an open set (which is of course what we are trying to prove) $x$ must have a neighborhood contained in $\bar{Y}^c$ which cannot intersect $\bar{y}$ by openness.

Comment: Nevermind, we have $\partial Y=\{x\in X| \text{For every neighborhood U of x holds}\,\, U\cap Y\neq\emptyset\,\,\text{and}\,\, U\cap (X\setminus Y)\neq\emptyset\}$. Thats where my conclusion came from. Because $x\notin\partial Y$ this $x$ holds that there exists a neighborhood with $U\cap Y=\emptyset$ or $U\cap (X\setminus Y)=\emptyset$. Also $x\notin Y$. Thats why it has to be $U\cap Y=\emptyset$. Thats at least what I thought.

Comment: You are right on the neighborhood. I made a mistake when looking it up again...

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, except you are forgetting that some neighborhood can be quite large (such as being the whole space). You definition of the boundary is spot on - from it, we can conclude that if $x \notin \partial Y$ then some neighborhood of $x$ must fail to contain a point inside $Y$ *and* a point outside $Y$.

Comment: Yes, that a neighborhood of $x$ can be even $X$ is clear to me, but since $x\notin\partial Y$ we can find such a neighborhood $U_x$ which satisfies the desired condition, or is it still wrong?

Comment: If $x \notin \partial Y$ and $x \notin Y$ then there is definitely a neighborhood of $x$ that doesn't intersect $\overline{Y}$, so your intuition is correct - however, assuming this is trivially equivalent to what you are trying to prove!

Comment: A suggestion of mine that should hopefully give you a bit more familiarity with the concept of the boundary is to try to prove the result this way: suppose $Y\subset X$. We wish to show $\overline{Y}$ is closed in the topology on $X$. We thus note  $\overline{Y}=Y\cup\partial Y$ and let $x$ be a limit point of $Y$. If $x \in Y$ we are done; if not, try to show that $x$ must be in the boundary of $Y$! Once you have done so, we know $Y$ contains its limit points and is thus closed

Comment: So I take a convergent sequence $(x_n)\in Y$ with $\lim x_n=x$. If $x\in Y$ we are done. If not it has to be in $\partial Y$? I will try that.

Comment: Careful: you should avoid sequences when talking about general topological spaces. It turns out sequences don't converge to single points anymore, but can converge to whole sets even! Also, note that my suggestion above is just that: a suggestion for another way to try to prove the result to gain familiarity with the boundary. Your original proof is pretty good though, so if you would prefer to patch your original proof up that would be good as well :)

Comment: Yes, this is my confusion when writing in english. I do not know all the translations...

Comment: Wait, I am confused now... Is my original proof now right, or wrong? Or what should be fixed? Edit: I thought the mistake made was fundamental and can not be fixed that easily.

Comment: There are definitely some issues with it, but it is not a lost cause! There are simply some steps you need to patch and up and find justification for, such as the assumption you made about all neighborhoods of $x$ not intersecting $Y$

Comment: Sorry that I am still asking on this, but is my justification I gave in the comments on why such a neighborhood $U_x$ exists fixing this part?

Comment: Looking through your comment above carefully, I would say your argument looks great, and fixes the issue you had. Well done!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Maybe the confusion we had arose, because I edited that comment afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to show:
>
> > Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $Y\subseteq X$. Then is $\overline{Y}$ closed.
>
> For my proof I want to write $X\setminus\overline{Y}$ as union of open sets.

Sounds like a good approach!

> Proof:
>
> It is $\overline{Y}=Y\cup\partial Y$.
>   Consider $X\setminus(Y\cup\partial Y)=\overline{Y}^c$.

Here, I might instead say something like this: "By definition, $\overline Y=Y\cup\partial Y.$ We show that $X\setminus\overline Y$ is a union of open sets, so is open."

> Let $x\in X\setminus(Y\cup\partial Y)$. Hence $x\notin Y$ and $x\notin\partial Y$.
>   Therefor for every neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ it is $U_x\cap Y=\emptyset$.

This isn't quite right. Rather, by definition of $\partial Y,$ since $x\notin Y,$ then *there exists* a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $U_x\cap Y=\emptyset.$

It's also a bit awkward, and there's a misspelling. I might say something like this: "Let $x\in X\setminus\overline Y.$ Since $\overline Y=Y\cup\partial Y,$ then by DeMorgan's Laws, $X\setminus\overline Y=(X\setminus Y)\cap(X\setminus\partial Y),$ so $x\notin Y$ and $x\notin\partial Y.$ Therefore, by definition of $\partial Y,$ there exists some neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $U_x\cap Y=\emptyset.$ Since $x\in X\setminus\overline Y$ was arbitrary, then such a $U_x$ exists for each such $x.$"

> Hence $U_x\subseteq X\setminus Y$ and $\overline{Y}^c\subseteq\underbrace{\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x}_{\text{open}}\subseteq X\setminus Y$.

Nicely done! There's really no purpose to mentioning that the union is open right now, though. I'd wait until the end. (See what I do there.)

> Now I want to show, that $\overline{Y}^c\supseteq\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x$.
>   Let $x'\in\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x$.
>
> I have to show, that $x'\notin Y$ and $x'\notin\partial Y$.

You can certainly proceed in this way, though since $X\setminus\overline Y=(X\setminus Y)\cap(X\setminus\partial Y),$ and since you've already shown that $$X\setminus\overline{Y}\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in X\setminus\overline Y}U_x\subseteq X\setminus Y,$$ then you need only show that $$\bigcup_{x\in X\setminus\overline Y}U_x\subseteq X\setminus\partial Y,$$ meaning that you only have to show $x'\notin\partial Y.$

> Since $x'\notin\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x\subseteq X\setminus Y$ is $x\notin Y$.

This doesn't make sense. It seems like you're trying to say that, since $x'\in\bigcup_{x\in X\setminus\overline Y}U_x\subseteq X\setminus Y,$ then $x'\notin Y.$ However, as I said, we don't even need to say this.

> Suppose $x'\in\partial Y$.

That's what I'd do!

> Then holds for every neighborhood $U_{x'}$ of $x'$, that $Y\cap U_{x'}\neq\emptyset$ and $U_{x'}\cap (X\setminus Y)\neq\emptyset$.
>   Which contradicts, that $U_{x'}\subseteq X\setminus Y$.

You've got the right idea, but it seems that you're trying to let $U_{x'}$ be simultaneously arbitrary and a specific counterexample. Instead, I'd say something like this: "By definition of $\partial Y,$ this means that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x',$ we have $U\cap Y\neq\emptyset.$ However, since $x'\in\bigcup_{x\in X\setminus\overline Y}U_x,$ then we have that $U_{x'}$ is a neighborhood of $x'$ disjoint from $Y,$ yielding the desired contradiction."

> We condlude, that $\overline{Y}^c=\bigcup_{x\in\overline{Y}^c} U_x$ open.
>   Hence $\overline{Y}$ is closed.

Here, I'd just say (if you lead off as I did by announcing your intention) something like: "We conclude that $$X\setminus\overline Y\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in X\setminus\overline Y}U_x\subseteq(X\setminus Y)\cap(X\setminus\partial Y)=X\setminus\overline Y,$$ so that $X\setminus\overline Y=\bigcup_{x\in X\setminus\overline Y}U_x.$ As a union of the open sets $U_x,$ we have that $X\setminus\overline Y$ is open, as we set out to show."

---

Let me know if you have any questions about my answer, or if you just want to bounce your phrasing adjustments off somebody.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I appreciate your comments very much. At the moment I do not have an open question.